# htdig stopped running - error loading shared libraries

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I've inherited a site with htdig installed. This has been running fine for years but it has suddenly stopped working. When vsiitng the URL in the browser I get the server misconfiguration error so I ran htsearch in command line/reviewed the errors and am receiving the following error:

./htsearch: error while loading shared libraries: libfuzzy-3.2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any thoughts greatly appreciated...the server recently rebooted so I'm wondering if I’m missing sym links etc.

--Update following comments--

After running strace the following is not found:

/usr/lib/htdig/tls/i686/sse2/libfuzzy-3.2.0.so

There is no library called htdif but it does exist elsewhere on the server, I guess I need to create the htdig library in /usr/local, is that correct and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: that library could be updated or not in the ld.so.conf's path or not in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. you can use strace to load the binary and see where it fails to load it.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, new teritory for me this. This response I get are lots of these with various different files:

Comment: mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7f9f000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/htdig/tls/i686/sse2/libfuzzy-3.2.0.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: there's no such file like `/usr/lib/htdig/tls/i686/sse2/libfuzzy-3.2.0.so` check the directory and its contents if it is there

Comment: That doesn't exist nor does /etc/ld.so.preload as far as I can tell - it does exist here though: /usr/local/htdig-3.2.0b6/lib/htdig/libfuzzy-3.2.0.so

Comment: the preload file you can skip. what linux system you got? you can download the htdig package which has the needed libraries

Comment: Hi Sergey, I have the libraries - they are all listed in /usr/local/htdig-3.2.0b6/lib/

Comment: well you can copy to that folder where it's searching or add this path /usr/local/htdig-3.2.0b6/lib/  into your /etc/ld.so.conf then run `ldconfig` to build the needed caches. or if you have the directory like `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` you create a config file with this path and run `ldconfig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Sergeys suggestions I have hit another issue but this stumbling block is behind me. Just in case anyone finds this I did the following:

After ascertaining that the program cannot load the libraries we need to add them to ld.so.conf. The libraries I wanted to add were:

- /usr/local/htdig-3.2.0b6/lib/htdig
- /usr/local/htdig-3.2.0b6/lib/htdig_db

Create a new file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d with the paths to the two directories above underneath one another

Reload the libraries by typing ldconfig, you can verify the changes by typing:

ldconfig -v | less